# Macro for displaying a name, date, and a hyperlink is not working?

Tags: macros, hyperref

I'm trying to create a macro that takes $4$ parameters. A name, a date, a hyperlink address, and text for the hyperlink. My macro is:

```
\newcommand\authordate[4]{\textbf{Author}: #1, #2. \\ \textbf{Source}:
\href{#3}{#4}}
```

However it's working, if I call it with the following:

```
\authordate{Joe, 2017, http://www.google.com, Google}
```

I get the error message:

```
! Paragraph ended before \hyper@n@rmalise was complete.
```

It should look like:

> **Author**: John, 2017.
>
> **Source**: [Google](http://www.google.com)

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: You say it should have 4 arguments. You would have to use `\authordate{Joe}{2017}{http://www.google.com}{Google}`.

Comment: Then please close/delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to transfer my comment to an answer: You defined the following:

```
\newcommand\authordate[4]{\textbf{Author}: #1, #2. \\ \textbf{Source}:
\href{#3}{#4}}
```

The `[4]` indicates you want it to have 4 arguments. The problem: TeX does not interpret lists like `a,b,c,d`. It wants them to have as `{a}{b}{c}{d}`.

So you need the following call to have it do its job:

```
\authordate{Joe}{2017}{http://www.google.com}{Google}
```